# Specifying digits (without decimal) in Python

Tags: python, formatting, digits

I'm trying to specify the number of digits (not decimal places) for a number output.  Specifically, I'm trying to make the output be a three digit number. For example: If a user inputs the number 7, the output is then 007.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> i = 7
>>> str(i).rjust(3, '0')
'007'
```

[rjust docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust)

Comment: Also excellent solution since i will eventually have to convert the number to a string.

Comment: @Viperwoman, Happy to help. Do note that *all* of these solutions give you a string. If they stayed ints they could have no padding.

Comment: Really?  I didn't know that (I'm a newbie at python).  Thank you for letting me know!

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> n = 7
>>> print format(n, '03d')
007
```

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> i = 7
>>> '%03d' % i
'007'
```

Comment: I like this solution since it's simple and elegant.  Thank you1

Answer (score 2):

Rounding out all the options:

```
>>> i = 7
>>> '{:03}'.format(i)
'007'
```

Answer (score 0):

All submitted answers sorted by time:

```
>>> timeit(lambda: '%03d' % 7, number=100000)
0.010141897959158541

>>> timeit(lambda: '{:03}'.format(7), number=100000)
0.046049894736881924

>>> timeit(lambda: str(7).rjust(3, '0'), number=100000)
0.04794490118149497

>>> timeit(lambda: format(7, '03d'), number=100000)
0.053364350161117083
```

Comment: I'd like to see a code where the time it takes to format this string is the bottleneck.

Comment: @SethMMorton not gonna happen. I did this of my own curiosity only. 5x speed difference was surprising but you're 100% right about its importance. Fortunately the fastest was probably also the most clear in this case, and what I would use regardless